# Trigger Emails - Not able to modify the FromAddress using TriggeredSendDefinition

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, java

I am trying to trigger send an email using TriggeredSendDefinition. Every time I am receiving an email from the DEFAULT account (Business unit email id).

I tried to give from address in `TriggeredSendDefinition` ,`Owner` and `SenderProfile`. But no luck.

How do I solve this issue? How do I modify the From Address during mail send?

Here is my code:

```
    ETClient client = new ETClient();
    Integer myEmailsId = 2648;
    String triggerSendsExternalKey = "MyTriggerSendTest";
    Soap stub = client.getSoapConnection().getSoap();

    TriggeredSendDefinition sendDefinition = new TriggeredSendDefinition();
    sendDefinition.setCustomerKey(triggerSendsExternalKey); // this is that External_Key
    sendDefinition.setPriority("High");
    sendDefinition.setTriggeredSendStatus(TriggeredSendStatusEnum.NEW);
    sendDefinition.setCCEmail("unknown@example.com;unknown@test.com");
    sendDefinition.setBccEmail("unknown@test.com");
    sendDefinition.setFromAddress("noreply@example.com");
    sendDefinition.setFromName("Bonjour <noreply@example.com>");
    sendDefinition.setReplyToAddress("abc@example.com");
    sendDefinition.setReplyToDisplayName("Example");
    sendDefinition.setEmailSubject("SomeTest");
    sendDefinition.setDynamicEmailSubject("This is Test EMAIL !!!");
    Owner owner = new Owner();
    owner.setFromName("FromName"); // At run time you change from user and email address
    owner.setFromAddress("example@example.com");

    sendDefinition.setOwner(owner);

    sendDefinition.setTriggeredSendType(TriggeredSendTypeEnum.CONTINUOUS);

    SendClassification sendClassification = new SendClassification();
    SenderProfile senderProfile = new SenderProfile();
    // senderProfile.setAutoReplyTriggeredSend(sendDefinition);
    senderProfile.setFromAddress("noreply@example.com");
    senderProfile.setFromName("Bonjour <noreply@example.com>");
    senderProfile.setReplyToAddress("abc@example.com");
    senderProfile.setReplyToDisplayName("Example");
    sendClassification.setSenderProfile(senderProfile);
    // sendClassification.setId(myEmailsId);
    sendDefinition.setSendClassification(sendClassification);

    Email email = new Email();
    email.setId(myEmailsId);
    email.setHtmlBody("<html><b>THIS IS A TEST</b></html>");
    email.setIsHTMLPaste(true);
    email.setHasDynamicSubjectLine(true);
    email.setSubject("This is Test mail");
    email.setTextBody("Test mail");

    com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal.List l1 = new com.exacttarget.fuelsdk.internal.List();
    l1.setId(myEmailsId);
    TriggeredSend triggeredSend = new TriggeredSend();
    triggeredSend.setId(myEmailsId);
    triggeredSend.setOwner(owner);
    ArrayList<String> to = new ArrayList<String>();
    to.add("unknown@example.com");

    sendDefinition.setEmail(email);

    for (String emailTo : to) {
        Subscriber sub = new Subscriber();
        // EMail to be sent
        sub.setEmailAddress(emailTo); // Subscriber to whom email should be
                                        // sent.
        sub.setSubscriberKey(emailTo);// Unique identifier for this email_Id
        sub.setStatus(SubscriberStatus.ACTIVE);
        Attribute att1 = new Attribute();
        att1.setName("First Name");
        att1.setValue("TestUser");
        Attribute att2 = new Attribute();
        att2.setName("EmailAddress");
        att2.setValue(emailTo);

        sub.getAttributes().add(att1);
        sub.getAttributes().add(att2);

        triggeredSend.getSubscribers().add(sub);
        l1.getSubscribers().add(sub);
        sendDefinition.setList(l1);
    }
    triggeredSend.setTriggeredSendDefinition(sendDefinition);
    CreateOptions createOptions = new CreateOptions();
    createOptions.setRequestType(RequestType.SYNCHRONOUS);
    CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest();
    createRequest.setOptions(createOptions);
    // createRequest.getObjects().add(replyMailManagementConfiguration);
    createRequest.getObjects().add(triggeredSend);
    CreateResponse createResponse = stub.create(createRequest);

    System.out.println("TriggeredSend :::  "+createResponse);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The from address is controlled by the [**Sender Classification (Profile)**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/) specified in the [**TriggeredSendDefinition**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/triggeredsenddefinition/).  It's possible to make it dynamic as you've suggested.

You'll need SFMC support to enable the **ENHANCED SENDER PROFILE** business rule (as referenced in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/47598/5202) by a SF staffer).

All you need after that is just to pass the attributes in your API call -- ones that match the names of your Profile Attributes (or variable names, depending on how you want to set those values).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have created Sender Classification and Sender Profiles. After that I have modified the Triggered Sends (Interactions -->Triggered Emails --> Under Messages, Email -->Triggered Sends) by changing the Send Classification with the newly created one. But still I am getting the mail from the DEFAULT profile.

Comment: Did you publish the trigger after the changes?

Comment: Ah now I am getting mail from the profile which I have created, after doing Pause + Publish Changes + Start/Restart . I did Pause + Save + Start/Restart before. Thanks for your help. For dynamic sender name and email I need to use AMPscript?